# Does this pair sequence converge??

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence, notation

First, I would like to understand what this sequence means,

$$
{\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{2+n}{3-4n} \\ \dfrac{\sin(n)}n \end{pmatrix}}
$$

I know that each sequence individual converges, top one converges to $\;-\dfrac14\;$, while the bottom converges to $\;0\;.$

But does this sequence as a whole converge?

Also, in this type of sequence,
$$
\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \\c_n\end{pmatrix} \in R^3 \;\right\} 
$$

In order for the sequence to diverge, would only one of the $3$ sequences need to diverge?

Comment: a sequence converges if and only if all components converge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the gamma function
$$A_n=\binom{\frac{n+2}{3-4 n}}{\frac{\sin (n)}{n}}=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5-3 n}{3-4 n}\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{\sin (n)}{n}\right)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{5-3 n}{3-4 n}-\frac{\sin (n)}{n}\right)}$$ For large values of $n$
$$A_n \sim \frac{n \left(16 n-11 \psi \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)}{(n-\gamma  \sin (n))
   \left(16 n-16 \psi\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \sin (n)-11 \psi
  \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)}\to 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Contemplate that

$$|a_n-A|<\epsilon\land|b_n-B|<\epsilon\implies\sqrt{(a_n-A)^2+(b_n-B)^2}<\sqrt2\epsilon$$
and
$$\sqrt{(a_n-A)^2+(b_n-B)^2}<\epsilon\implies|a_n-A|<\epsilon\land|b_n-B|<\epsilon.$$

This can be used to show that component-wise convergence is equivalent to vector convergence.